# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).final_countdown is not a function | Already loaded needed files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load a `countdown js`, but when I launch the final script I get the common `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).final_countdown is not a function` error.
I saw I have to load jQuery before the countdown, and so I did, but still not working.

This was a working [example](http://jsbin.com/qabocuqori/edit?html,js,output) of the countdown, the fact is how do I integrate it in this website where I get the error?

To go to the website click [here](http://www.lnf.infn.it/user.html) > search and click Scientific Committee > Click Previous Meetings

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Comment: https://final-countdown.pragmaticmates.com/jquery.final-countdown.js throws an `502` error

Comment: How to fix it @Andreas

Comment: It's gonna solve future errors like this one (TypeError: $(...).final_countdown is not a function) or at least when solved I will change my question for that @Quentin

Comment: Did you fix the problem? Got the same problem using this plugin.

Comment: @KevinLieser Mmmm I think I did, unfortunately I forgot to update the question... if I’m not wrong it should have been a date issue, make sure parameters you input are correct

Answer (score -1):

final_countdown is also depends on kineticjs library: [See requirements section](http://see%20requirements%20in%20github) Try to add kineticjs before final_countdown script:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kineticjs/5.2.0/kinetic.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you add kineticjs library script to your html before final_countdown?

Comment: I did, didn't you check the head of the page?

Answer (score -1):

```
Try Changing the date: Currently its Jan 1 2015

var start = Math.round(new Date("Jan 1 2015 08:00").getTime()/1000);
var now = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
var end = start + (122 * 86400); // 86400 = 1 day
$('.countdown').final_countdown({
          'now': now,
               'start': start,
               'end': end
               });


and keep a local copy of coutdown js
```

//  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).final_countdown is not a function  might just get resolved

Comment: Change it into what?

Comment: Like Jan 1 2017... i mean to say the date and time when the countdown should reach 0

Comment: Yes I did. Keep a local copy of countdown js.

Comment: And? Sorry but I don't get what you want me to do to fix the problem :)

Comment: 1. I tried accessing the countdown.js file on the server path which you have set.. Initially there was timeout. To avoid that situation my suggestion is to download the file from external server to your hosting environment. 2.     The date has to be changed to future date else you will see 0 days 0hours and 0sec

Comment: But still nothing works, which date you suggest to edit? Start Now or End??